# How to php inside html generated via php

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between single quote and double quote string in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php)

I need to include some php code within some html file that I generate via PHP.

I have tried the following but this is not working. Can you explain to me why?

```
<?php
$text='mc';
echo '<text>"$text"</text>'
?>
```

Comment: Also read up on [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) strings.

Comment: echo `"<text>$text</text>";` will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you should use in this case `echo "<text>\"$text\"</text>"`

Read more about the different kinds of strings in PHP in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php) and in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

You can also use String concatenation, like this:
`echo '<text>' . $text . '</text>'`

Which way you prefer is totally up to you.

Comment: ... or `echo '<text>', $text, '</text>';`

Comment: A link to variable interpolation in the PHP manual would be beneficial here.

Comment: I tried it still not. How isn't it I dont understand

Comment: @Vulcan I'm trying to find a good link to the PHP manual, feel free to add one if you know the link...

Comment: Oops, there's actually no such page in the PHP manual, the Wikipedia page was the one I was thinking of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_interpolation

Comment: @Vulcan I don't think variable interpolation is exactly what the OP is looking for though...

Comment: Variable interpolation is the *exact* reason for the OP's original code not working as he expected it to.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you meant variable interpolation as in getting a variable who's name is contained in another variable. As the `${'test_'.$i}` on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
<?php
$text='mc';
echo '<text>'.$text.'</text>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text='mc';
echo '<text>'.$text.'</text>'
//or
echo "<text>$text</text>";
?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice the usage difference between single quote and double quote. The following resource will help you.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

```
<?php
$text = 'mc';
echo '<text>'.$text.'</text>';
echo '<text>',$text,'</text>';
echo "<text>$text</text>";
echo "<text>{$text}</text>";?>
```

You can refer to the [string manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) at php.net for further usage.